# Replacing data on array list from index n to x

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two Integer type `ArrayLists`. How would I go about replacing the values of `ArrayList` 1 from index 5 to 10 with values of the same Index from `ArrayList` 2, without having to type it all separately?

What I tried to do :

```
ArrayList1.set(5, Arraylist2.get(5)); // Set 5th index of Arraylist1 to 5th of Arraylist2
ArrayList1.set(6, ArrayList2.get(6));
```

.....

```
ArrayList1.set(10, ArrayList.get(10));
```

While this certainly works, it takes a lot of lines of code and gets kind of hard to read.

Comment: Just use a `for`  loop ?

Comment: Didn't think of that! Works for me.

Comment: You can use a [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to iterate over the indices you want to pick up then you can do what ever you want with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a loop like this :

```
int startIndex = 5;
int endIndex = 10;
for(int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++){
   arrayList1.set(i, arraylist2.get(i));
   //-------------^-----------------^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

references :

- [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(int,%20java.util.Collection))
- [remove range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange(int,%20int))

---

```
yourOldList.removeRange(fromIndex,toIndex);
yourOldList.addAll(fromIndex,yourNewList);
```

Answer (score 0):

In adition to the other answers you can handle such an issue by utilising the Java 8 feature streams:

`arli1.stream().filter( e->(arli1.indexOf( e ) > startIndex && arli1.indexOf( e ) < endIndex)).map( e->arli2.set( arli1.indexOf(e), e ) ).count();`

Which, to be fair, might be a little bit over the top for your particular issue but it works with interal iterations which performs quicker when a lot of data is processed.

Note:  `count()`  at the end of the stream is necessary to force the stream to execute since  `filter()`  and  `map()`  are "lazy" operations and need an "eager" operation to run. But any other eager method would to do the trick as well.